# trouble with else statment

Tags: php, if-statement, advanced-custom-fields

Im having some trouble with a else statement i'm trying to write. Basicly if the repeater field is there and displays the content do that, if no content is in the repeater field display this.

Here is the original code without the else statement that I started from

```
                <div class="tabs-panel" id="panel5">
                <?php 
                if ( have_rows( 'ar_content' ) ):
                    $i = 0;
                    $n = count( get_field('ar_content') ); 
                ?>
                    <div class="row">
                        <?php 
                        while ( have_rows( 'ar_content' ) ): 
                            the_row();
                            $i++;
                        ?>
                            <div class="small-12 medium-4 columns">
                                <?php the_sub_field('ar_block'); ?>
                            </div>
                            <? if ($i % 3 == 0 && $i < $n) : ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                        <?php 
                            endif;
                        endwhile; 
                        ?>
                    </div>
                <? endif; ?>
            </div><!-- end panel 5 -->
```

Here is the code I am trying to get working. I would think its would be just replace the last endif with a else and move on the to else content?

```
                <div class="tabs-panel" id="panel5">
                <?php 
                if ( have_rows( 'ar_content' ) ):
                    $i = 0;
                    $n = count( get_field('ar_content') ); 
                ?>
                    <div class="row">
                        <?php 
                        while ( have_rows( 'ar_content' ) ): 
                            the_row();
                            $i++;
                        ?>
                            <div class="small-12 medium-4 columns">
                                <?php the_sub_field('ar_block'); ?>
                            </div>
                            <? if ($i % 3 == 0 && $i < $n) : ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                        <?php 
                            endif;
                        endwhile; 
                        ?>
                    </div>
                <? } else { ?>
                <h2>content to show if nothing is above</h2>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </div><!-- end panel 5 -->
```

Not working though, any thoughts. And yes if this is totally jacked i'm new to PHP

Comment: Either use `if() {} else {}` or `if() : else: endif;` I recommend the former one as it does not confuses than the later one..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using wrong syntax, please read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php), change:

```
<? } else { ?>
```

to:

```
<? else: ?>
```

You should use *either* the `colon` *or* the `brackets` syntax, but not both.

Comment: Or better yet, move to using `if () { } else { }` across the board :P

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="tabs-panel" id="panel5">
            <?php
            if ( have_rows( 'ar_content' ) ) {
                $i = 0;
            }
$n = count( get_field('ar_content') );
?>
<div class="row">
<?php
    if(have_rows( 'ar_content' )){
        while ( have_rows( 'ar_content' ) ){
        the_row();
        $i++;
    ?>
        <div class="small-12 medium-4 columns">
            <?php the_sub_field('ar_block'); ?>
        </div>
        <? if ($i % 3 == 0 && $i < $n) { ?>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <?php
            } // endif;
            } // endwhile;
        ?>
        </div>
<?php } else {
        echo "<h2>content to show if nothing is above</h2>";
     }
?>
```

This is what you need.